# Failed to start MariaDB 10.2.16 database server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

When I have entered `systemctl status mariadb.service`

The output is:

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.2.16 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-07-17 13:53:46 +06; 24s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 7342 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 7058 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && system
  Process: 7054 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7052 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7342 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Jul 17 13:53:43 munim-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.2.16 database server...
Jul 17 13:53:43 munim-Inspiron-5548 mysqld[7342]: 2018-07-17 13:53:43 139955312822464 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.2.16-MariaDB-10.2.16+m
Jul 17 13:53:46 munim-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 17 13:53:46 munim-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.2.16 database server.
Jul 17 13:53:46 munim-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 17 13:53:46 munim-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have tried to login `mysql -u root -p` it shows

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Can anyone give me any suggestion?

Comment: Try to look at the log file - probably something like `/var/lib/mysql/mariadb.log` but to be certain please look for the `log-error` option in your `my.cnf` config file

Comment: look at `journalctl -xu mariadb.service`

Comment: Did you got any success in solving this ?? am stuck in same irritating issue.. :-(